# JavaScript: How to calculate offsets for a boundary of a moving sprite when it's speed is relative to time?

Tags: javascript, math, canvas, html5-canvas, game-development

I am current running into a bit of a math conundrum that has stumped me for days.

I am building a JavaScript game and attempting to create boundary coordinates to manage the pathing and movement of sprites, however it appears that lag/jitter/delay is reeking havoc on different entities moving in coordination with one another.

I believe I must calculate the jitter/lag/offset and somehow apply it to the coordinate range detection and movement functions but I have yet to crack the code correctly and alleviate the mis-aligning sprites.

Here is a replication of the issue in a CodeSandbox and the bulk of the code that shows it in action:
https://codesandbox.io/s/movetime-boundries-issue-example-2prow?file=/src/App.js

```
  var obj = { x: 10, speed: 250 };
  var obj2 = { x: 100 };

  var objHighestX = { max: 0 };

  var direction = 0;

  var canvas = document.getElementById("mainScene");
  var ctx = canvas && canvas.getContext("2d");
  ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;

  ctx.font = "15px Courier";
  var render = function () {};

  var update = function (modifier) {
    // console.log("Updating");
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.clientWidth, canvas.clientHeight);
    ctx.fillRect(obj2.x, 60, 15, 15);
    if (obj.x > objHighestX.max) {
      objHighestX.max = obj.x;
    }
    ctx.fillText(String("X" + obj.x), 25, 100);
    ctx.fillText(String("Furthest" + objHighestX.max), 125, 100);
    if (obj.x >= obj2.x - 15) {
      direction = 1;
    } else if (obj.x <= 0) {
      direction = 0;
    }
    if (direction === 0) {
      obj.x += obj.speed * modifier;
      ctx.clearRect(obj.x - 7, 9, 17, 17);
      ctx.fillRect(obj.x, 60, 15, 15);
    }
    if (direction === 1) {
      obj.x -= obj.speed * modifier;
      ctx.clearRect(obj.x, 9, 17, 17);
      ctx.fillRect(obj.x, 60, 15, 15);
    }
  };
  var lastUpdate = Date.now();
  // The main game loop
  var main = function () {
    var now = Date.now();
    var delta = now - lastUpdate;
    lastUpdate = now;
    update(delta / 1000);
    render();
    requestAnimationFrame(main);
  };
  main();
```

If anyone has any suggestions or questions towards my case, I'm very eager to hear of it.

Perhaps I have to use the rate of change to create an offset for the boundaries?

Which I've tried like:

```
    if (obj.x >= obj2.x - (15 * 1 * modifier))
```

But am still not yet getting this one down. Thank you all, greatly, in advance.

Answer (score 1):

First, you're delta time calculations aren't complete.

```
var now = Date.now();
var delta = now - lastUpdate;
lastUpdate = now;
update(delta / 1000);
```

If you now request `update()` to be invoked via requestAnimationFrame, the number passed as a parameter will be the number of miliseconds passed between the last and the current frame. So if the screen refresh rate is 60hz it's roughly 16.6ms.

This value alone though isn't meaningful - you need to compare it against a target value.

Say we want to achieve a framerate of 30fps - equal to ~33.3ms. If we take this value and divide it from the 16.6ms above, we get roughly 0.5. This makes complete sense. We want 30fps, the monitor refreshes at 60hz, so everything should move at half the speed.

Let's modify your `main()` function to reflect that:

```
 var main = function() {
   var targetFrameRate = 30;
   var frameTime = 1000 / targetFrameRate;
   var now = Date.now();
   var delta = now - lastUpdate;
   lastUpdate = now;
   update(delta / frameTime);
   render();
   requestAnimationFrame(main);
 };
```

Second problem is the `update()` function itself.
Let's have a look at the following block:

```
if (direction === 0) {
  obj.x += obj.speed * modifier;
  ctx.clearRect(obj.x - 7, 9, 17, 17);
  ctx.fillRect(obj.x, 60, 15, 15);
}
```

That means, wherever **obj** currently is, move it to the right by some amount. We are missing the boundary check at this point. You need to check if it **would** leave the bounds if we **would** move it to the right. In case it does, just move it next to the bounds.

[image]

Something like this:

```
var maxX=100;
 if (direction === 0) {
   var speed = obj.speed * modifier;
   if (obj.x + obj.width + speed > maxX) {
     direction = 1;
     obj.x = maxX - obj.width;
   } else {
     obj.x += speed;
   }
 }
```

Comment: Wow! This makes absolute sense!

Thank you so much for taking the time to read and draw out your approach to this inquiry. I'll update this tonight after plugging these into my from scratch game engine and seeing it in action. Thank you again so much for the help and amazing elaboration.

Answer (score 1):

### Maintain correct speed during collision frame

I notice that the object is always moving, which means the given answer does not correctly solve the problem.

An object should not slow down between frames if it has a constant speed

The illustration shows an object moving

[image]

- At top how far it would move without interruption.
- At center the point of collision. Note that there is still a lot of distance needed to cover to maintain the same speed.
- At bottom the object is moved left the remaining distance such the total distance traveled matches the speed.

To maintain speed the total distance traveled between frames must remain the same. Positioning the object at the point of collision reduces the distance traveled and thus the speed of the object during the collision frame can be greatly reduced

The correct calculation is as follows

```
 const directions = {
     LEFT: 0,
     RIGHT: 1,
 };
 const rightWallX = 100;
 const leftWallX = 0;

 if (obj.direction === directions.RIGHT) {
     obj.x = obj.x + obj.speed;
     const remainDist = (rightWallX - obj.width) - obj.x;
     if (remainDist <= 0) {
         obj.direction = directions.LEFT;
         obj.x = (rightWallX - obj.width) + remainDist;
     }
 } else if (obj.direction === directions.LEFT) {
     obj.x = obj.x - obj.speed;
     const remainDist = leftWallX - obj.x;
     if (remainDist >= 0) {
         obj.direction = directions.RIGHT;
         obj.x = leftWallX + remainDist;
     }
 }
```

Comment: I REALLY like this answer!

By calculating the remaining distance and procedurally moving based on that number and the object's speed, I have perfectly stopped overflow of the boundaries. Blindman, you sure have some great insight :)

Thank you so much for this brilliant answer. <3

Comment: @Blindman67 Though your point is indeed correct of course, I'm wondering if I should post another answer claiming that yours 'does not correctly solve the problem' as it ignores the fact that the object loses energy as it bounces off the obstacle, there's friction caused by the collision & potential air-resistance and the object thus should be somewhere more close to the obstacle?

Comment: @obscure The question does not include any drag or collision loss however it does have a constant velocity which is why I posted

Comment: @Blindman67 No problem, forgot what I said. Today's not the best day so maybe I took things a bit too personal.