# How to redraw canvas by onClick event within few seconds in different position?

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5-canvas

I want to redraw canvas multiple times on different positions within few seconds from bottom until user's selected button/link.
[image]

From example image,
if user click 5th floor items then the lift should move slowly until 5th floor from ground floor. Thanks for any kind of approach.
From the code that attached, if click any floor items, the lift moving directly until that level because I put fixed size. what I need is to move the lift slowly until selected floor. Hope I can make everyone understand the scenario.

```js
function load() {
   var context = document.getElementById('main').getContext("2d");
   context.moveTo(80,0);
   context.lineTo(80,1000);
   context.moveTo(50,0);
   context.lineTo(50,1000);
   context.moveTo(110,0);
   context.lineTo(110,1000);
   context.font = "20px Arial";
   context.fillText("G",130,940);
   context.fillText("1st",130,850);
   context.fillText("2nd",130,760);
   context.fillText("3rd",130,670);
   context.fillText("4th",130,580);
   context.fillText("5th",130,495);
   context.fillText("6th",130,405);
   context.fillText("7th",130,315);
   context.fillText("8th",130,225);
   context.fillText("9th",130,135);
   context.fillText("10th",125,50);
   context.stroke();

   var floorTen = document.getElementById('floorTen');
   var floorNine = document.getElementById('floorNine');
   var floorEight = document.getElementById('floorEight');
   var floorSeven = document.getElementById('floorSeven');
   var floorSix = document.getElementById('floorSix');
   var floorFive = document.getElementById('floorFive');
   var floorFour = document.getElementById('floorFour');
   var floorThree = document.getElementById('floorThree');
   var floorTwo = document.getElementById('floorTwo');
   var floorOne = document.getElementById('floorOne');
   var floorG = document.getElementById('floorG');

   //default position
   var posX = 48;
   var posY = 905;

   //floor distance
   var snapG = 10;
   var snap1 = 90;
   var snap2 = 185;
   var snap3 = 270;
   var snap4 = 360;
   var snap5 = 450;
   var snap6 = 540;
   var snap7 = 620;
   var snap8 = 710;
   var snap9 = 800;
   var snap10 = 890;

  var imgLoaded = false;

   var img = new Image();
   //img.src = "http://via.placeholder.com/50x50";
   img.src = "Elevatorai.png";

   img.onload = function() {
      imgLoaded = true;
      context.drawImage(img, posX, posY, img.width/21, img.height/29);
   };


   // Floor button click
   floorTen.onclick = function() {
      if (!imgLoaded) return;
      posY = posY - snap10;
      context.clearRect(0, 0, context.canvas.width, context.canvas.height);
      context.moveTo(80,0);
      context.lineTo(80,1000);
      context.moveTo(50,0);
      context.lineTo(50,1000);
      context.moveTo(110,0);
      context.lineTo(110,1000);
      context.font = "20px Arial";
      context.fillText("G",130,940);
      context.fillText("1st",130,850);
      context.fillText("2nd",130,760);
      context.fillText("3rd",130,670);
      context.fillText("4th",130,580);
      context.fillText("5th",130,495);
      context.fillText("6th",130,405);
      context.fillText("7th",130,315);
      context.fillText("8th",130,225);
      context.fillText("9th",130,135);
      context.fillText("10th",125,50);
      context.stroke();
      context.drawImage(img, posX, posY, img.width/21, img.height/29);
   };

   floorNine.onclick = function() {
      if (!imgLoaded) return;
      posY = posY - snap9;
      context.clearRect(0, 0, context.canvas.width, context.canvas.height);
      context.moveTo(80,0);
      context.lineTo(80,1000);
      context.moveTo(50,0);
      context.lineTo(50,1000);
      context.moveTo(110,0);
      context.lineTo(110,1000);
      context.font = "20px Arial";
      context.fillText("G",130,940);
      context.fillText("1st",130,850);
      context.fillText("2nd",130,760);
      context.fillText("3rd",130,670);
      context.fillText("4th",130,580);
      context.fillText("5th",130,495);
      context.fillText("6th",130,405);
      context.fillText("7th",130,315);
      context.fillText("8th",130,225);
      context.fillText("9th",130,135);
      context.fillText("10th",125,50);
      context.stroke();
      context.drawImage(img, posX, posY, img.width/21, img.height/29);
   };

   floorEight.onclick = function() {
      if (!imgLoaded) return;
      posY = posY - snap8;
      context.clearRect(0, 0, context.canvas.width, context.canvas.height);
      context.moveTo(80,0);
      context.lineTo(80,1000);
      context.moveTo(50,0);
      context.lineTo(50,1000);
      context.moveTo(110,0);
      context.lineTo(110,1000);
      context.font = "20px Arial";
      context.fillText("G",130,940);
      context.fillText("1st",130,850);
      context.fillText("2nd",130,760);
      context.fillText("3rd",130,670);
      context.fillText("4th",130,580);
      context.fillText("5th",130,495);
      context.fillText("6th",130,405);
      context.fillText("7th",130,315);
      context.fillText("8th",130,225);
      context.fillText("9th",130,135);
      context.fillText("10th",125,50);
      context.stroke();
      context.drawImage(img, posX, posY, img.width/21, img.height/29);
   };

   floorSeven.onclick = function() {
      if (!imgLoaded) return;
      posY = posY - snap7;
      context.clearRect(0, 0, context.canvas.width, context.canvas.height);
      context.moveTo(80,0);
      context.lineTo(80,1000);
      context.moveTo(50,0);
      context.lineTo(50,1000);
      context.moveTo(110,0);
      context.lineTo(110,1000);
      context.font = "20px Arial";
      context.fillText("G",130,940);
      context.fillText("1st",130,850);
      context.fillText("2nd",130,760);
      context.fillText("3rd",130,670);
      context.fillText("4th",130,580);
      context.fillText("5th",130,495);
      context.fillText("6th",130,405);
      context.fillText("7th",130,315);
      context.fillText("8th",130,225);
      context.fillText("9th",130,135);
      context.fillText("10th",125,50);
      context.stroke();
      context.drawImage(img, posX, posY, img.width/21, img.height/29);
   };

   floorSix.onclick = function() {
      if (!imgLoaded) return;
      posY = posY - snap6;
      context.clearRect(0, 0, context.canvas.width, context.canvas.height);
      context.moveTo(80,0);
      context.lineTo(80,1000);
      context.moveTo(50,0);
      context.lineTo(50,1000);
      context.moveTo(110,0);
      context.lineTo(110,1000);
      context.font = "20px Arial";
      context.fillText("G",130,940);
      context.fillText("1st",130,850);
      context.fillText("2nd",130,760);
      context.fillText("3rd",130,670);
      context.fillText("4th",130,580);
      context.fillText("5th",130,495);
      context.fillText("6th",130,405);
      context.fillText("7th",130,315);
      context.fillText("8th",130,225);
      context.fillText("9th",130,135);
      context.fillText("10th",125,50);
      context.stroke();
      context.drawImage(img, posX, posY, img.width/21, img.height/29);
   };

   floorFive.onclick = function() {
      if (!imgLoaded) return;
      posY = posY - snap5;
      context.clearRect(0, 0, context.canvas.width, context.canvas.height);
      context.moveTo(80,0);
      context.lineTo(80,1000);
      context.moveTo(50,0);
      context.lineTo(50,1000);
      context.moveTo(110,0);
      context.lineTo(110,1000);
      context.font = "20px Arial";
      context.fillText("G",130,940);
      context.fillText("1st",130,850);
      context.fillText("2nd",130,760);
      context.fillText("3rd",130,670);
      context.fillText("4th",130,580);
      context.fillText("5th",130,495);
      context.fillText("6th",130,405);
      context.fillText("7th",130,315);
      context.fillText("8th",130,225);
      context.fillText("9th",130,135);
      context.fillText("10th",125,50);
      context.stroke();
      context.drawImage(img, posX, posY, img.width/21, img.height/29);
   };

   floorFour.onclick = function() {
      if (!imgLoaded) return;
      posY = posY - snap4;
      context.clearRect(0, 0, context.canvas.width, context.canvas.height);
      context.moveTo(80,0);
      context.lineTo(80,1000);
      context.moveTo(50,0);
      context.lineTo(50,1000);
      context.moveTo(110,0);
      context.lineTo(110,1000);
      context.font = "20px Arial";
      context.fillText("G",130,940);
      context.fillText("1st",130,850);
      context.fillText("2nd",130,760);
      context.fillText("3rd",130,670);
      context.fillText("4th",130,580);
      context.fillText("5th",130,495);
      context.fillText("6th",130,405);
      context.fillText("7th",130,315);
      context.fillText("8th",130,225);
      context.fillText("9th",130,135);
      context.fillText("10th",125,50);
      context.stroke();
      context.drawImage(img, posX, posY, img.width/21, img.height/29);
   };

   floorThree.onclick = function() {
      if (!imgLoaded) return;
      posY = posY - snap3;
      context.clearRect(0, 0, context.canvas.width, context.canvas.height);
      context.moveTo(80,0);
      context.lineTo(80,1000);
      context.moveTo(50,0);
      context.lineTo(50,1000);
      context.moveTo(110,0);
      context.lineTo(110,1000);
      context.font = "20px Arial";
      context.fillText("G",130,940);
      context.fillText("1st",130,850);
      context.fillText("2nd",130,760);
      context.fillText("3rd",130,670);
      context.fillText("4th",130,580);
      context.fillText("5th",130,495);
      context.fillText("6th",130,405);
      context.fillText("7th",130,315);
      context.fillText("8th",130,225);
      context.fillText("9th",130,135);
      context.fillText("10th",125,50);
      context.stroke();
      context.drawImage(img, posX, posY, img.width/21, img.height/29);
   };

   floorTwo.onclick = function() {
      if (!imgLoaded) return;
      posY = posY - snap2;
      context.clearRect(0, 0, context.canvas.width, context.canvas.height);
      context.moveTo(80,0);
      context.lineTo(80,1000);
      context.moveTo(50,0);
      context.lineTo(50,1000);
      context.moveTo(110,0);
      context.lineTo(110,1000);
      context.font = "20px Arial";
      context.fillText("G",130,940);
      context.fillText("1st",130,850);
      context.fillText("2nd",130,760);
      context.fillText("3rd",130,670);
      context.fillText("4th",130,580);
      context.fillText("5th",130,495);
      context.fillText("6th",130,405);
      context.fillText("7th",130,315);
      context.fillText("8th",130,225);
      context.fillText("9th",130,135);
      context.fillText("10th",125,50);
      context.stroke();
      context.drawImage(img, posX, posY, img.width/21, img.height/29);
   };

   floorOne.onclick = function() {
      if (!imgLoaded) return;
      posY = posY - snap1;
      context.clearRect(0, 0, context.canvas.width, context.canvas.height);
      context.moveTo(80,0);
      context.lineTo(80,1000);
      context.moveTo(50,0);
      context.lineTo(50,1000);
      context.moveTo(110,0);
      context.lineTo(110,1000);
      context.font = "20px Arial";
      context.fillText("G",130,940);
      context.fillText("1st",130,850);
      context.fillText("2nd",130,760);
      context.fillText("3rd",130,670);
      context.fillText("4th",130,580);
      context.fillText("5th",130,495);
      context.fillText("6th",130,405);
      context.fillText("7th",130,315);
      context.fillText("8th",130,225);
      context.fillText("9th",130,135);
      context.fillText("10th",125,50);
      context.stroke();
      context.drawImage(img, posX, posY, img.width/21, img.height/29);
   };

   floorG.onclick = function() {
      if (!imgLoaded) return;
      //posY = posY + snapG;
      context.clearRect(0, 0, context.canvas.width, context.canvas.height);
      context.moveTo(80,0);
      context.lineTo(80,1000);
      context.moveTo(50,0);
      context.lineTo(50,1000);
      context.moveTo(110,0);
      context.lineTo(110,1000);
      context.font = "20px Arial";
      context.fillText("G",130,940);
      context.fillText("1st",130,850);
      context.fillText("2nd",130,760);
      context.fillText("3rd",130,670);
      context.fillText("4th",130,580);
      context.fillText("5th",130,495);
      context.fillText("6th",130,405);
      context.fillText("7th",130,315);
      context.fillText("8th",130,225);
      context.fillText("9th",130,135);
      context.fillText("10th",125,50);
      context.stroke();
      context.drawImage(img, posX, posY, img.width/21, img.height/29);
   };
}
```

```css
.shadow1{
  box-shadow: 3px 7px 3px gray;
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;

}
.shadow1:hover{
  transform: scale(1.05);
}


#main {
  background-color: gray;
}

/* Media query for Mobile devices*/

@media only screen and (min-width: 285px) and (max-width: 480px) {

}
/* Media Query for Tablets */

@media only screen and (min-width: 481px) and (max-width: 1024px) {

}
/* Desktops and laptops  */

@media only screen and (min-width: 1025px) {

}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-2 bg-primary">
    <h5>Advertisement</h5>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-10 bg-light">
    <h5 class="text-center mt-4">Floor Selection</h5>
    <div class="row pb-5 no-gutters" style="padding-left: 100px; padding-right: 100px;">
      <div class="col-sm-2 mt-2 text-center">
        <canvas id="main" width="200px" height="1000px"></canvas>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-8">
        <div class="col-sm-12 mt-3 p-3 shadow1" style="background-color: rgb(213, 216, 218);">
          <button id="floorTen" class="text-dark btn btn-default" style="text-decoration: none;"><h6><strong>Home & Office Furniture</strong></h6></button>
          <a href="" id="" class="text-dark" style="text-decoration: none; color: rgb(75, 73, 71);"> <span style="margin-left: 10px;">|</span> <span style="margin-left: 20px;">Home Appliances & Accessories</span></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12 mt-3 p-3 shadow1" style="background-color: rgb(213, 216, 218);">
          <button id="floorNine" class="text-dark btn btn-default" style="text-decoration: none;"><h6><strong>Ready Food & Beverages</strong></h6></button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12 mt-3 p-3 shadow1" style="background-color: rgb(213, 216, 218);">
          <button id="floorEight" class="text-dark btn btn-default" style="text-decoration: none;"><h6><strong>Toys & Gadgets Offices Stationaries & Accessories</strong></h6></button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12 mt-3 p-3 shadow1" style="background-color: rgb(213, 216, 218);">
          <button id="floorSeven" class="text-dark btn btn-default" style="text-decoration: none;"><h6><strong>Halal Products & Goods</strong></h6></button>
          <a href="" id="floorSeven" class="text-dark" style="text-decoration: none; color: rgb(75, 73, 71);"><span style="margin-left: 10px;">|</span> <span style="margin-left: 20px;">Retails Stores</span></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12 mt-3 p-3 shadow1" style="background-color: rgb(213, 216, 218);">
          <button id="floorSix" class="text-dark btn btn-default" style="text-decoration: none;"><h6><strong>Electronics</strong></h6></button>
          <a href="" id="floorSix" class="" style="margin-left: 50px; text-decoration: none; color: rgb(75, 73, 71);"> Mobile & Tablets</a>
          <a href="" id="floorSix" class="" style="margin-left: 20px; text-decoration: none; color: rgb(75, 73, 71);"> Mobile Accessories</a>
          <a href="" id="floorSix" class="" style="margin-left: 20px; text-decoration: none; color: rgb(75, 73, 71);"> Camera</a>
          <a href="" id="floorSix" class="" style="margin-left: 20px; text-decoration: none; color: rgb(75, 73, 71);"> IT Accessories Computers, Printer & Laptop</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12 mt-3 p-3 shadow1" style="background-color: rgb(213, 216, 218);">
          <button id="floorFive" class="text-dark btn btn-default" style="text-decoration: none;"><h6><strong>Sport Clothes Male & Accessories</strong></h6></button>
          <a href="" id="floorFive" class="" style="text-decoration: none; color: rgb(75, 73, 71);"><span style="margin-left: 10px;">|</span> <span style="margin-left: 20px;">Swim Suit Male & Female</span></a>
          <a href="" id="floorFive" class="" style="text-decoration: none; color: rgb(75, 73, 71);"><span style="margin-left: 10px;">|</span> <span style="margin-left: 20px;">Gym & Other Sports Equipments</span></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12 mt-3 p-3 shadow1" style="background-color: rgb(213, 216, 218);">
          <button id="floorFour" class="text-dark btn btn-default" style="text-decoration: none;"><h6><strong>Jewelry & Accessories</strong></h6></button>
          <a href="" id="floorFour" class="" style="margin-left: 50px; text-decoration: none; color: rgb(75, 73, 71);"> Jewelry</a>
          <a href="" id="floorFour" class="" style="margin-left: 20px; text-decoration: none; color: rgb(75, 73, 71);"> Trinkets Jewelry</a>
          <a href="" id="floorFour" class="" style="margin-left: 20px; text-decoration: none; color: rgb(75, 73, 71);"> Sun Glasses</a>
          <a href="" id="floorFour" class="" style="margin-left: 20px; text-decoration: none; color: rgb(75, 73, 71);"> Watches</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12 mt-3 p-3 shadow1" style="background-color: rgb(213, 216, 218);">
          <button id="floorThree" class="text-dark btn btn-default" style="text-decoration: none;"> <h6><strong>Beauty</strong></h6></button>
          <a href="" id="floorThree" class="" style="margin-left: 50px; text-decoration: none; color: rgb(75, 73, 71);"> Cosmetics</a>
          <a href="" id="floorThree" class="" style="margin-left: 20px; text-decoration: none; color: rgb(75, 73, 71);"> Skin Care</a>
          <a href="" id="floorThree" class="" style="margin-left: 20px; text-decoration: none; color: rgb(75, 73, 71);"> Hair Care</a>
          <a href="" id="floorThree" class="" style="margin-left: 20px; text-decoration: none; color: rgb(75, 73, 71);"> Perfumes (Male & Female)</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12 mt-3 p-3 shadow1" style="background-color: rgb(213, 216, 218);">
          <button id="floorTwo" class="text-dark btn btn-default" style="text-decoration: none;"><h6><strong>Man Fashion</strong></h6></button>
          <a href="" id="floorTwo" class="" style="margin-left: 50px; text-decoration: none; color: rgb(75, 73, 71);"> Clothes</a>
          <a href="" id="floorTow" class="" style="margin-left: 20px; text-decoration: none; color: rgb(75, 73, 71);"> Shoes & Bags</a>
          <a href="" id="floorTwo" class="" style="margin-left: 20px; text-decoration: none; color: rgb(75, 73, 71);"> Leather Items</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12 mt-3 p-3 shadow1" style="background-color: rgb(213, 216, 218);">
          <button id="floorOne" class="text-dark btn btn-default" style="text-decoration: none;"><h6><strong>Women Fashion</strong></h6></button>
          <a href="" id="floorOne" class="" style="margin-left: 50px; text-decoration: none; color: rgb(75, 73, 71);"> Clothes</a>
          <a href="" id="floorOne" class="" style="margin-left: 20px; text-decoration: none; color: rgb(75, 73, 71);"> Lingeries</a>
          <a href="" id="floorOne" class="" style="margin-left: 20px; text-decoration: none; color: rgb(75, 73, 71);"> Shoes & Bags</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12 mt-3 p-3 shadow1" style="background-color: rgb(213, 216, 218);">
          <button id="floorG" class="text-dark btn btn-default" style="text-decoration: none;"><h6><strong>Backyard</strong></h6></button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-2">People will be moving here</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we should really try to clean your code a little bit as there's a lot of repetition which makes maintaining a bit hard.

You have eleven buttons which essentially all do the same thing once clicked:

- update a single variable
- redraw canvas

At the moment you manually attach all the above actions to each one of the buttons.

e.g.

```
var floorG = document.getElementById('floorG');
floorG.onclick = function() {
      if (!imgLoaded) return;
      //posY = posY + snapG;
      context.clearRect(0, 0, context.canvas.width, context.canvas.height);
      context.moveTo(80,0);
      context.lineTo(80,1000);
      context.moveTo(50,0);
      context.lineTo(50,1000);
      context.moveTo(110,0);
      context.lineTo(110,1000);
      context.font = "20px Arial";
      context.fillText("G",130,940);
      context.fillText("1st",130,850);
      context.fillText("2nd",130,760);
      context.fillText("3rd",130,670);
      context.fillText("4th",130,580);
      context.fillText("5th",130,495);
      context.fillText("6th",130,405);
      context.fillText("7th",130,315);
      context.fillText("8th",130,225);
      context.fillText("9th",130,135);
      context.fillText("10th",125,50);
      context.stroke();
      context.drawImage(img, posX, posY, img.width/21, img.height/29);
   };
```

So the above is repeated eleven times!

It would be better to wrap the functionality once inside a function and attach the same function to each button:
To do this, let's create an array of objects, where each object holds the id to the button as well as a target position for the elevator.

```
var myButtons = [
    {id: "floorG",snap: 10},
    {id: "floorOne",snap: 90},
    {id: "floorTwo", snap: 185},
    {id: "floorThree", snap: 270},
    {id: "floorFour", snap: 360},
    {id: "floorFive", snap: 450},
    {id: "floorSix",snap: 540},
    {id: "floorSeven",snap: 620},
    {id: "floorEight", snap: 710},
    {id: "floorNine", snap: 800},
    {id: "floorTen", snap: 890}
];
```

Now we're able to simply loop over this array, grab an id plus the target position and create a click event listener for the appropriate button:

```
function buttonClick(e) {
  if (!imgLoaded) return;
  targY = e.currentTarget.snap;
}
var theButton;
for (var a = 0; a < myButtons.length; a++) {
  theButton = document.getElementById(myButtons[a].id);
  theButton.snap = myButtons[a].snap;
  theButton.onclick = buttonClick;
}
```

The actual movement of the elevator ain't that hard actually. We just need a function that constantly updates the canvas based on the target position for the elevator. Additionally it would be great if the elevator doesn't just move from a to b in a linear way - it should slow down as it approaches it's destination. This effect is called **easing**.
Let's create another function `updateCanvas()`

```
function updateCanvas() {
  posY = ((posY - targY) * 0.9 + targY);

  context.clearRect(0, 0, context.canvas.width, context.canvas.height);
  context.moveTo(80, 0);
  context.lineTo(80, 1000);
  context.moveTo(50, 0);
  context.lineTo(50, 1000);
  context.moveTo(110, 0);
  context.lineTo(110, 1000);
  context.font = "20px Arial";
  context.fillText("G", 130, 940);
  context.fillText("1st", 130, 850);
  context.fillText("2nd", 130, 760);
  context.fillText("3rd", 130, 670);
  context.fillText("4th", 130, 580);
  context.fillText("5th", 130, 495);
  context.fillText("6th", 130, 405);
  context.fillText("7th", 130, 315);
  context.fillText("8th", 130, 225);
  context.fillText("9th", 130, 135);
  context.fillText("10th", 125, 50);
  context.stroke();
  context.drawImage(img, posX, posY + img.height / 2, img.width, img.height);
}
```

In the above code we're recalculating the elevator's position based on it's current position and the destination - targY.

```
posY = ((posY - targY) * 0.9 + targY)
```

The factor **0.9** controls the speed of the movement - which is as faster as it's getting closer to **1**.

Now everything that's missing is some mechanism to call this function periodically. This is done by utilizing the `setInterval()` method. It calls a given function in a fixed interval.

Here's the complete example (Just click on 'Run code snippet'):

```js
var context = document.getElementById('main').getContext("2d");

var myButtons = [
  {id: "floorG",snap: 10},
  {id: "floorOne",snap: 90},
  {id: "floorTwo", snap: 185},
  {id: "floorThree", snap: 270},
  {id: "floorFour", snap: 360},
  {id: "floorFive", snap: 450},
  {id: "floorSix",snap: 540},
  {id: "floorSeven",snap: 620},
  {id: "floorEight", snap: 710},
  {id: "floorNine", snap: 800},
  {id: "floorTen", snap: 890}
];

var posX = 48;
var posY = 905;
var targY = posY;

var imgLoaded = false;
var img = new Image();

img.onload = function() {
  imgLoaded = true;
  context.drawImage(img, posX, posY, img.width / 21, img.height / 29);
};
img.src = "http://via.placeholder.com/50x50";


function updateCanvas() {
  posY = ((posY - targY) * 0.9 + targY);

  context.clearRect(0, 0, context.canvas.width, context.canvas.height);
  context.beginPath();
  context.moveTo(80, 0);
  context.lineTo(80, 1000);
  context.moveTo(50, 0);
  context.lineTo(50, 1000);
  context.moveTo(110, 0);
  context.lineTo(110, 1000);
  context.font = "20px Arial";
  context.fillText("G", 130, 940);
  context.fillText("1st", 130, 850);
  context.fillText("2nd", 130, 760);
  context.fillText("3rd", 130, 670);
  context.fillText("4th", 130, 580);
  context.fillText("5th", 130, 495);
  context.fillText("6th", 130, 405);
  context.fillText("7th", 130, 315);
  context.fillText("8th", 130, 225);
  context.fillText("9th", 130, 135);
  context.fillText("10th", 125, 50);
  context.stroke();
  context.drawImage(img, posX, posY + img.height / 2, img.width, img.height);
}

function buttonClick(e) {
  if (!imgLoaded) return;
  targY = e.currentTarget.snap;
}
var theButton;
for (var a = 0; a < myButtons.length; a++) {
  theButton = document.getElementById(myButtons[a].id);
  theButton.snap = myButtons[a].snap;
  theButton.onclick = buttonClick;
}

var interval = setInterval(updateCanvas, 20);
```

```css
.shadow1 {
  box-shadow: 3px 7px 3px gray;
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}

.shadow1:hover {
  transform: scale(1.05);
}

#main {
  background-color: gray;
}


/* Media query for Mobile devices*/

@media only screen and (min-width: 285px) and (max-width: 480px) {}


/* Media Query for Tablets */

@media only screen and (min-width: 481px) and (max-width: 1024px) {}


/* Desktops and laptops  */

@media only screen and (min-width: 1025px) {}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-2 bg-primary">
    <h5>Advertisement</h5>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-10 bg-light">
    <h5 class="text-center mt-4">Floor Selection</h5>
    <div class="row pb-5 no-gutters" style="padding-left: 100px; padding-right: 100px;">
      <div class="col-sm-2 mt-2 text-center">
        <canvas id="main" width="200px" height="1000px"></canvas>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-8">
        <div class="col-sm-12 mt-3 p-3 shadow1" style="background-color: rgb(213, 216, 218);">
          <button id="floorTen" class="text-dark btn btn-default" style="text-decoration: none;"><h6><strong>Home & Office Furniture</strong></h6></button>
          <a href="" id="" class="text-dark" style="text-decoration: none; color: rgb(75, 73, 71);"> <span style="margin-left: 10px;">|</span> <span style="margin-left: 20px;">Home Appliances & Accessories</span></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12 mt-3 p-3 shadow1" style="background-color: rgb(213, 216, 218);">
          <button id="floorNine" class="text-dark btn btn-default" style="text-decoration: none;"><h6><strong>Ready Food & Beverages</strong></h6></button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12 mt-3 p-3 shadow1" style="background-color: rgb(213, 216, 218);">
          <button id="floorEight" class="text-dark btn btn-default" style="text-decoration: none;"><h6><strong>Toys & Gadgets Offices Stationaries & Accessories</strong></h6></button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12 mt-3 p-3 shadow1" style="background-color: rgb(213, 216, 218);">
          <button id="floorSeven" class="text-dark btn btn-default" style="text-decoration: none;"><h6><strong>Halal Products & Goods</strong></h6></button>
          <a href="" id="floorSeven" class="text-dark" style="text-decoration: none; color: rgb(75, 73, 71);"><span style="margin-left: 10px;">|</span> <span style="margin-left: 20px;">Retails Stores</span></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12 mt-3 p-3 shadow1" style="background-color: rgb(213, 216, 218);">
          <button id="floorSix" class="text-dark btn btn-default" style="text-decoration: none;"><h6><strong>Electronics</strong></h6></button>
          <a href="" id="floorSix" class="" style="margin-left: 50px; text-decoration: none; color: rgb(75, 73, 71);"> Mobile & Tablets</a>
          <a href="" id="floorSix" class="" style="margin-left: 20px; text-decoration: none; color: rgb(75, 73, 71);"> Mobile Accessories</a>
          <a href="" id="floorSix" class="" style="margin-left: 20px; text-decoration: none; color: rgb(75, 73, 71);"> Camera</a>
          <a href="" id="floorSix" class="" style="margin-left: 20px; text-decoration: none; color: rgb(75, 73, 71);"> IT Accessories Computers, Printer & Laptop</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12 mt-3 p-3 shadow1" style="background-color: rgb(213, 216, 218);">
          <button id="floorFive" class="text-dark btn btn-default" style="text-decoration: none;"><h6><strong>Sport Clothes Male & Accessories</strong></h6></button>
          <a href="" id="floorFive" class="" style="text-decoration: none; color: rgb(75, 73, 71);"><span style="margin-left: 10px;">|</span> <span style="margin-left: 20px;">Swim Suit Male & Female</span></a>
          <a href="" id="floorFive" class="" style="text-decoration: none; color: rgb(75, 73, 71);"><span style="margin-left: 10px;">|</span> <span style="margin-left: 20px;">Gym & Other Sports Equipments</span></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12 mt-3 p-3 shadow1" style="background-color: rgb(213, 216, 218);">
          <button id="floorFour" class="text-dark btn btn-default" style="text-decoration: none;"><h6><strong>Jewelry & Accessories</strong></h6></button>
          <a href="" id="floorFour" class="" style="margin-left: 50px; text-decoration: none; color: rgb(75, 73, 71);"> Jewelry</a>
          <a href="" id="floorFour" class="" style="margin-left: 20px; text-decoration: none; color: rgb(75, 73, 71);"> Trinkets Jewelry</a>
          <a href="" id="floorFour" class="" style="margin-left: 20px; text-decoration: none; color: rgb(75, 73, 71);"> Sun Glasses</a>
          <a href="" id="floorFour" class="" style="margin-left: 20px; text-decoration: none; color: rgb(75, 73, 71);"> Watches</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12 mt-3 p-3 shadow1" style="background-color: rgb(213, 216, 218);">
          <button id="floorThree" class="text-dark btn btn-default" style="text-decoration: none;"> <h6><strong>Beauty</strong></h6></button>
          <a href="" id="floorThree" class="" style="margin-left: 50px; text-decoration: none; color: rgb(75, 73, 71);"> Cosmetics</a>
          <a href="" id="floorThree" class="" style="margin-left: 20px; text-decoration: none; color: rgb(75, 73, 71);"> Skin Care</a>
          <a href="" id="floorThree" class="" style="margin-left: 20px; text-decoration: none; color: rgb(75, 73, 71);"> Hair Care</a>
          <a href="" id="floorThree" class="" style="margin-left: 20px; text-decoration: none; color: rgb(75, 73, 71);"> Perfumes (Male & Female)</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12 mt-3 p-3 shadow1" style="background-color: rgb(213, 216, 218);">
          <button id="floorTwo" class="text-dark btn btn-default" style="text-decoration: none;"><h6><strong>Man Fashion</strong></h6></button>
          <a href="" id="floorTwo" class="" style="margin-left: 50px; text-decoration: none; color: rgb(75, 73, 71);"> Clothes</a>
          <a href="" id="floorTow" class="" style="margin-left: 20px; text-decoration: none; color: rgb(75, 73, 71);"> Shoes & Bags</a>
          <a href="" id="floorTwo" class="" style="margin-left: 20px; text-decoration: none; color: rgb(75, 73, 71);"> Leather Items</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12 mt-3 p-3 shadow1" style="background-color: rgb(213, 216, 218);">
          <button id="floorOne" class="text-dark btn btn-default" style="text-decoration: none;"><h6><strong>Women Fashion</strong></h6></button>
          <a href="" id="floorOne" class="" style="margin-left: 50px; text-decoration: none; color: rgb(75, 73, 71);"> Clothes</a>
          <a href="" id="floorOne" class="" style="margin-left: 20px; text-decoration: none; color: rgb(75, 73, 71);"> Lingeries</a>
          <a href="" id="floorOne" class="" style="margin-left: 20px; text-decoration: none; color: rgb(75, 73, 71);"> Shoes & Bags</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12 mt-3 p-3 shadow1" style="background-color: rgb(213, 216, 218);">
          <button id="floorG" class="text-dark btn btn-default" style="text-decoration: none;"><h6><strong>Backyard</strong></h6></button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-2">People will be moving here</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

## Edit

As you asked in the comments - yes it's possible to change the colors during movement of the 'elevator'. I modifed my previous example to change the text color.
To make this work we need to check the current vertical screen position of the elevator and compare it to the position of each text box. That means we need to group the textes and it's positions in another array as that makes things in the update loop a little easier.

```
var floors=[{name: "G",xPos: 130, yPos: 940},
{name: "1st",xPos: 130, yPos: 850},
{name: "2nd",xPos: 130, yPos: 760 },
{name: "3rd",xPos: 130, yPos: 670},
{name: "4th",xPos: 130, yPos: 580},
{name: "5th",xPos: 130, yPos: 495},
{name: "6th",xPos: 130, yPos: 405},
{name: "7th",xPos: 130, yPos: 315},
{name: "8th",xPos: 130, yPos: 225},
{name: "9th",xPos: 130, yPos: 135},
{name: "10th",xPos: 125, yPos: 50}
];
```

Now we can easily loop over this array, check if the elevator is within a certain range to one of the yPos positions above and in case it is, use a different textcolor.
Additionally, if the elevator reached it's destination targY, we're clearing the interval and setting the textcolor to another color now because actually it isn't necessary to keep on redrawing the canvas if the elevator is standing still.

Here's the complete code:

```js
var context = document.getElementById('main').getContext("2d");

var myButtons = [
  {id: "floorG",snap: 10},
  {id: "floorOne",snap: 90},
  {id: "floorTwo", snap: 185},
  {id: "floorThree", snap: 270},
  {id: "floorFour", snap: 360},
  {id: "floorFive", snap: 450},
  {id: "floorSix",snap: 540},
  {id: "floorSeven",snap: 620},
  {id: "floorEight", snap: 710},
  {id: "floorNine", snap: 800},
  {id: "floorTen", snap: 890}
];

var floors=[{name: "G",xPos: 130, yPos: 940},
{name: "1st",xPos: 130, yPos: 850},
{name: "2nd",xPos: 130, yPos: 760 },
{name: "3rd",xPos: 130, yPos: 670},
{name: "4th",xPos: 130, yPos: 580},
{name: "5th",xPos: 130, yPos: 495},
{name: "6th",xPos: 130, yPos: 405},
{name: "7th",xPos: 130, yPos: 315},
{name: "8th",xPos: 130, yPos: 225},
{name: "9th",xPos: 130, yPos: 135},
{name: "10th",xPos: 125, yPos: 50}
];
var posX = 48;
var posY = 905;
var targY = posY;
var interval;

var imgLoaded = false;
var img = new Image();

img.onload = function() {
  imgLoaded = true;
  context.drawImage(img, posX, posY, img.width / 21, img.height / 29);
};
img.src = "http://via.placeholder.com/50x50";


function updateCanvas() {
  posY = ((posY - targY) * 0.9 + targY);

  context.clearRect(0, 0, context.canvas.width, context.canvas.height);
  context.fillStyle = "black";
  context.beginPath();
  context.moveTo(80, 0);
  context.lineTo(80, 1000);
  context.moveTo(50, 0);
  context.lineTo(50, 1000);
  context.moveTo(110, 0);
  context.lineTo(110, 1000);
  context.font = "20px Arial";

  var floor;
  for (var a = 0; a < floors.length; a++) {
    floor = floors[a];

    if (Math.abs((posY + img.height / 2) - floor.yPos) < 30) {
      if (Math.abs(posY - targY) < 1) {
        context.fillStyle = "green";
        clearInterval(interval);
        interval = null;
      } else {
        context.fillStyle = "blue";
      }
    } else {
      context.fillStyle = "black";
    }
    context.fillText(floor.name, floor.xPos, floor.yPos);
  }

  context.stroke();
  context.drawImage(img, posX, posY + img.height / 2, img.width, img.height);
}

function buttonClick(e) {
  if (!imgLoaded) return;
  targY = e.currentTarget.snap;
  if(interval==null)
  {
    interval = setInterval(updateCanvas, 20);
  }
}
var theButton;
for (var a = 0; a < myButtons.length; a++) {
  theButton = document.getElementById(myButtons[a].id);
  theButton.snap = myButtons[a].snap;
  theButton.onclick = buttonClick;
}

interval = setInterval(updateCanvas, 20);
```

```css
.shadow1 {
  box-shadow: 3px 7px 3px gray;
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}

.shadow1:hover {
  transform: scale(1.05);
}

#main {
  background-color: gray;
}


/* Media query for Mobile devices*/

@media only screen and (min-width: 285px) and (max-width: 480px) {}


/* Media Query for Tablets */

@media only screen and (min-width: 481px) and (max-width: 1024px) {}


/* Desktops and laptops  */

@media only screen and (min-width: 1025px) {}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-2 bg-primary">
    <h5>Advertisement</h5>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-10 bg-light">
    <h5 class="text-center mt-4">Floor Selection</h5>
    <div class="row pb-5 no-gutters" style="padding-left: 100px; padding-right: 100px;">
      <div class="col-sm-2 mt-2 text-center">
        <canvas id="main" width="200px" height="1000px"></canvas>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-8">
        <div class="col-sm-12 mt-3 p-3 shadow1" style="background-color: rgb(213, 216, 218);">
          <button id="floorTen" class="text-dark btn btn-default" style="text-decoration: none;"><h6><strong>Home & Office Furniture</strong></h6></button>
          <a href="" id="" class="text-dark" style="text-decoration: none; color: rgb(75, 73, 71);"> <span style="margin-left: 10px;">|</span> <span style="margin-left: 20px;">Home Appliances & Accessories</span></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12 mt-3 p-3 shadow1" style="background-color: rgb(213, 216, 218);">
          <button id="floorNine" class="text-dark btn btn-default" style="text-decoration: none;"><h6><strong>Ready Food & Beverages</strong></h6></button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12 mt-3 p-3 shadow1" style="background-color: rgb(213, 216, 218);">
          <button id="floorEight" class="text-dark btn btn-default" style="text-decoration: none;"><h6><strong>Toys & Gadgets Offices Stationaries & Accessories</strong></h6></button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12 mt-3 p-3 shadow1" style="background-color: rgb(213, 216, 218);">
          <button id="floorSeven" class="text-dark btn btn-default" style="text-decoration: none;"><h6><strong>Halal Products & Goods</strong></h6></button>
          <a href="" id="floorSeven" class="text-dark" style="text-decoration: none; color: rgb(75, 73, 71);"><span style="margin-left: 10px;">|</span> <span style="margin-left: 20px;">Retails Stores</span></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12 mt-3 p-3 shadow1" style="background-color: rgb(213, 216, 218);">
          <button id="floorSix" class="text-dark btn btn-default" style="text-decoration: none;"><h6><strong>Electronics</strong></h6></button>
          <a href="" id="floorSix" class="" style="margin-left: 50px; text-decoration: none; color: rgb(75, 73, 71);"> Mobile & Tablets</a>
          <a href="" id="floorSix" class="" style="margin-left: 20px; text-decoration: none; color: rgb(75, 73, 71);"> Mobile Accessories</a>
          <a href="" id="floorSix" class="" style="margin-left: 20px; text-decoration: none; color: rgb(75, 73, 71);"> Camera</a>
          <a href="" id="floorSix" class="" style="margin-left: 20px; text-decoration: none; color: rgb(75, 73, 71);"> IT Accessories Computers, Printer & Laptop</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12 mt-3 p-3 shadow1" style="background-color: rgb(213, 216, 218);">
          <button id="floorFive" class="text-dark btn btn-default" style="text-decoration: none;"><h6><strong>Sport Clothes Male & Accessories</strong></h6></button>
          <a href="" id="floorFive" class="" style="text-decoration: none; color: rgb(75, 73, 71);"><span style="margin-left: 10px;">|</span> <span style="margin-left: 20px;">Swim Suit Male & Female</span></a>
          <a href="" id="floorFive" class="" style="text-decoration: none; color: rgb(75, 73, 71);"><span style="margin-left: 10px;">|</span> <span style="margin-left: 20px;">Gym & Other Sports Equipments</span></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12 mt-3 p-3 shadow1" style="background-color: rgb(213, 216, 218);">
          <button id="floorFour" class="text-dark btn btn-default" style="text-decoration: none;"><h6><strong>Jewelry & Accessories</strong></h6></button>
          <a href="" id="floorFour" class="" style="margin-left: 50px; text-decoration: none; color: rgb(75, 73, 71);"> Jewelry</a>
          <a href="" id="floorFour" class="" style="margin-left: 20px; text-decoration: none; color: rgb(75, 73, 71);"> Trinkets Jewelry</a>
          <a href="" id="floorFour" class="" style="margin-left: 20px; text-decoration: none; color: rgb(75, 73, 71);"> Sun Glasses</a>
          <a href="" id="floorFour" class="" style="margin-left: 20px; text-decoration: none; color: rgb(75, 73, 71);"> Watches</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12 mt-3 p-3 shadow1" style="background-color: rgb(213, 216, 218);">
          <button id="floorThree" class="text-dark btn btn-default" style="text-decoration: none;"> <h6><strong>Beauty</strong></h6></button>
          <a href="" id="floorThree" class="" style="margin-left: 50px; text-decoration: none; color: rgb(75, 73, 71);"> Cosmetics</a>
          <a href="" id="floorThree" class="" style="margin-left: 20px; text-decoration: none; color: rgb(75, 73, 71);"> Skin Care</a>
          <a href="" id="floorThree" class="" style="margin-left: 20px; text-decoration: none; color: rgb(75, 73, 71);"> Hair Care</a>
          <a href="" id="floorThree" class="" style="margin-left: 20px; text-decoration: none; color: rgb(75, 73, 71);"> Perfumes (Male & Female)</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12 mt-3 p-3 shadow1" style="background-color: rgb(213, 216, 218);">
          <button id="floorTwo" class="text-dark btn btn-default" style="text-decoration: none;"><h6><strong>Man Fashion</strong></h6></button>
          <a href="" id="floorTwo" class="" style="margin-left: 50px; text-decoration: none; color: rgb(75, 73, 71);"> Clothes</a>
          <a href="" id="floorTow" class="" style="margin-left: 20px; text-decoration: none; color: rgb(75, 73, 71);"> Shoes & Bags</a>
          <a href="" id="floorTwo" class="" style="margin-left: 20px; text-decoration: none; color: rgb(75, 73, 71);"> Leather Items</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12 mt-3 p-3 shadow1" style="background-color: rgb(213, 216, 218);">
          <button id="floorOne" class="text-dark btn btn-default" style="text-decoration: none;"><h6><strong>Women Fashion</strong></h6></button>
          <a href="" id="floorOne" class="" style="margin-left: 50px; text-decoration: none; color: rgb(75, 73, 71);"> Clothes</a>
          <a href="" id="floorOne" class="" style="margin-left: 20px; text-decoration: none; color: rgb(75, 73, 71);"> Lingeries</a>
          <a href="" id="floorOne" class="" style="margin-left: 20px; text-decoration: none; color: rgb(75, 73, 71);"> Shoes & Bags</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12 mt-3 p-3 shadow1" style="background-color: rgb(213, 216, 218);">
          <button id="floorG" class="text-dark btn btn-default" style="text-decoration: none;"><h6><strong>Backyard</strong></h6></button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-2">People will be moving here</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You must add `context.beginPath()` before adding more paths (eg `context.moveTo` and or `context.lineTo`) . As it is now it adds the same lines every interval, After a few minuets it will be drawing the same lines 100 times each interval, Let it run too long and render time will kill the page (may crash page on some devices).. Also use `requestAnimationFrame` rather than `interval` as it has a far better sync with the hardware display VSync.

Comment: @Blindman67 You're aware that I could tell you the same, you told me recently? To cite: `'The question does not include..'`.. a request to find & fix any possible bug inside the original code snippet. Also I'm completely aware of the advantages of requestAnimationFrame - for this use-case though it doesn't offer any benefits and is like breaking a butterfly on a wheel. This ain't a demanding 3d game - we're talking about a single object moving up and down, which fits a plain interval just well.

Comment: You have presented an answer that has a fatal bug . Please take a moment and add the correction as pointed out in my first comment. You are referring to comments `The question does not include.` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67040507/javascript-how-to-calculate-offsets-for-a-boundary-of-a-moving-sprite-when-its/67060084#comment118561793_67060084

Comment: @Blindman67 I added the context.beginPath() as you said then it removes the page crashing error.

Comment: @obscure is it possible to change color of each floor while elevator moving and destination floor color also to be green so that it would be more interactive for users?

Comment: @sAyEd It is very important to clear out old sub paths before creating new ones. MDN link for more info. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/beginPath also you should use `requestAnimationFrame` to get the best quality animation https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame

Comment: @sAyEd No problem - glad I could help! I'm not sure about your question with the different colors. You mean the text or the area behind?

Comment: @Blindman67 I totally agree about `beginPath` but as I indicated I just copied out the original code without noticing. requestAnimationFrame however is a different story. In this scenario it just adds unnecessary complexity as you now have to deal with different refresh rates and there's absolutely nothing wrong with just sticking to an interval. If I would have seen a single benefit I'd surely have recommended requestAnimationFrame myself.

Comment: @obscure I mean like real lift moving got red color indicating for each floor right. so i want same thing for this use case. For example, user click 5th floor. now while elevator passing 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th floor there should have color indicating and finally 5th floor should stick with green color and so on for the rest. please let me know if I still not able to make you understood :)

Comment: @obscure I got it in your edited code. You are really appreciated man!